# Vba Excel Sum Countifs - invalid character { }

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with a Sum Countifs formula in VBA. I have tried Brackets and an array . Below is the Array attempt

```
Dim finRow As String

finRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A500000").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Macro").Range("B51") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("E2:E" & finRow), Array("Positions - Active Recruitment", "Positions - Not Actively Recruiting"), .Range("B2:B" & finRow), "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$E$3").Value, .Range("Y2:Y" & finRow), "=Contingent Worker", .Range("T2:T" & finRow), "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$D$3").Value))
```

Below is the Bracket attempt which gives me invalid character errors in VBA

```
Sheets("Macro").Range("B51") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("E2:E" & finRow), {""=Positions - Active Recruitment"", ""Positions - Not Actively Recruiting""}, .Range("B2:B" & finRow), "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$E$3").Value, .Range("Y2:Y" & finRow), "=Contingent Worker", .Range("T2:T" & finRow), "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$D$3").Value))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you! Matt

Comment: Remove the "=" sign `"=Active"` and use "Active" and so on for others and try it?

Comment: *UNTESTED* Try this `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("E2:E" & finRow), "Active", .Range("B2:B" & finRow),  Sheets("Macro").Range("$E$3").Value, .Range("T2:T" & finRow),  Sheets("Macro").Range("$D$3").Value)`

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear earlier. I have updated it accordingly. Previously I posted an example that worked without the sum function. I am having trouble with the summing within a countif. Thank you for your response

Comment: If you change `Array("Positions - Active Recruitment", "Positions - Not Actively Recruiting")` to `"Positions - *Active*Recruit*"` then you can find both via Wildcards without bringing Arrays into it

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Chronocidal